# Humanmade | Custom meta box class: How to display a repeatable meta box group?

Tags: loop, metabox, post-meta

I'm using the [Humanmade | Custom meta box class](https://github.com/humanmade/Custom-Meta-Boxes) to add meta boxes to my themes admin pages.

I have integrated the class and have been enjoying the use of adding meta box's to my current projects immensely. I've now come into an area where I'm very stuck.

### I have a created a repeatable meta box group.

```
$featurettes = array(

    array( 'id' => 'a_feat_img', 'name' => 'Featurette Illustration or image',                'type' => 'image', 'cols' => 4, 'show_size' => true ),

    array( 'id' => 'a_feat_head',  'name' => 'Featurette heading', 'type' => 'text', 'cols' => 4 ),

    array( 'id' => 'a_feat_sub',  'name' => 'Featurette subheading or description', 'type' => 'textarea', 'cols' => 4 )
);

$group_featurettes = $featurettes;
foreach ( $group_featurettes as &$featurette ) {
    $featurette['id'] = str_replace( 'featurette', 'gfeaturette', $featurette['id'] );
}

$meta_boxes[] = array(
    'title' => 'About Page Featurettes',
    'pages' => 'page',
    'show_on' => array( 'id' => array( 6 ) ),
    'fields' => array(
        array( 
            'id' => 'a_f_gp', 
            'name' => 'Featurette Panels', 
            'type' => 'group', 
            'repeatable' => true,
            'sortable' => true,
            'fields' => $group_featurettes,
            'desc' => 'Create featurettes.'
        ),
    )
);
```

**In the back end this works perfectly.**

## As far as I've got with displaying the meta.

```
<section class="row featurette-wrap">

    <aside class="large-4 columns featurette-img">
        <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'a_feat_img', true ), 'thumbnail', false, array( 'class' => 'vert-align-mid' ) ); ?>
    </aside>
    <article class="large-8 columns featurette-text">
        <?php 
            $groups = get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'a_f_gp', false );

            foreach ( $groups as $group ) {        
                echo '<h2 class="vert-align-mid">' . $group['a_feat_head'] . '</h2>';
                echo '<h4 class="vert-align-mid">' . $group['a_feat_sub'] . '</h4>';
            }
        ?>      
    </article>
</section>
```

### What I'd like to do

I want to create a loop that displays a new `<section class="row featurette-wrap">` and everything in it for each repeated group made in the admin area.

**What I have here**

```
<?php 
    $groups = get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'a_f_gp', false );

    foreach ( $groups as $group ) {        
        echo '<h2 class="vert-align-mid">' . $group['a_feat_head'] . '</h2>';
        echo '<h4 class="vert-align-mid">' . $group['a_feat_sub'] . '</h4>';
    }
?>
```

**Will display new information but I'd like to include the whole group and it's containing elements.**

Can anyone point me in the right direction with this? Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated.

**Thanks**

Comment: Have you tried http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom

Comment: @Wyck Thanks for the suggestion. It's helped me get some way there to understanding my next steps.